# The word 'behance' appears instead of my title in Google search results

Tags: google, search, title

I've just noticed that when I search for articles on my website in Google, the name of my website has been replaced with 'behance'.

I have no idea who/what 'behance' is and how to correct this problem.

When I look at the page source, the name of my website (Once Upon a Food Blog) is there. If I search for 'behance' in the source code there are no results.

If you were to type in 'cloudy homemade lemonade' into Google my post comes up on the first page as:

'Homemade Cloudy Lemonade - behance' instead of 'Homemade Cloudy Lemonade - Once Upon a Food Blog'.

Can anyone explain why this might be happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: Your site isn't the only one.  Here are four others in Google search results:  http://i.imgur.com/p4XhbLs.png

Comment: @StephenOstermiller interesting that they are all food related.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller you got my curiosity piqued.  All those sites seem to have a different theme, apart from being food blogs I can't see a connection.

Comment: They all use the phrase "one upon a".   That is how I found them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I contacted John Mueller at Google about this issue.  He had his team take a look at it and got back to me with the answer.

The word "behance" is coming from an SVG image on your page.  The image is https://onceuponafoodblog.com/wp-content/plugins/simple-social-icons/symbol-defs.svg and it has a number of `<title>` elements in its source code, the first of which is "behance":

[image]

Google is incorrectly picking the title from this image as the brand name of your site.   I think that Google looks for images used on the home page to try to determine the brand name.  Google is probably looking for logos.

You can:

- remove this image from your site
- or edit the image to change the word "behance" to your actual site name
- or disallow the image in your robots.txt file.

After you have done so, use "Fetch as Google" in Google Search Console against your home page to get site display updated in the Google search results.

> What's happening here is that we're (unnecessarily :)) picking up a title from a SVG that's used on those pages ( https://onceuponafoodblog.com/wp-content/plugins/simple-social-icons/symbol-defs.svg ). So obscure :). It's useful having an example like this, thanks for passing it on! If they want, one fix is to robot out the SVG and request the homepage be recrawled & reindexed in Search Console.
>
> Cheers
>   John

Comment: Thanks for looking into it for me - I have successfully sorted the issue! I would never have figured it out myself - what an obscure cause!!

Comment: Right...just when I thought this was sorted...I have deleted the SVG file and also added it to the robots.txt file to disallow. Asked Google to re-index the site again, but the word 'behance' is still appearing.  Is there any other place that the word 'behance' could be being used? If so, how can I find this out?  Thanks in advance again!

Comment: font-awesome.min.css also has "fa-behance" in it, but I doubt that would do it.

Answer (score 2):

Behance is a network of sites and services specializing in self-promotion, including consulting and online portfolio sites.   If you (or someone) has added your site there, then it is likely that Google search has discovered your site through that portal and is kind of acknowledging that.

Comment: Behance.net also has a "food blog" theme for WordPress: https://www.behance.net/gallery/16015547/Food-Blog-A-Wordpress-Theme  Maybe that is confusing Google because the title of the site is "Once Upon a Food Blog".